# grep content display in table

Tags: unix

suppose file has contents as

```
A=abc, B=fl, C=asd
A=59, B=sadl, C=asd
A=ab40c, B=sad, C=asd
```

i did a grep and got some lines from it, not i need to display it in this format

```
A      B     C
abc    fl    asd
59     sad1  asd
```

or

```
A  |    B    | C
abc |   fl   | asd
59  |   sad1  |asd
```

kinda?

bad thing is with the grep, i have uniq-c,sort -rn also which displays occurence in reverse order, now i need to get this field also in table under **count**

like this

```
 count |   A  |    B    | C
 3    |    abc |   fl   | asd
 5    |    59  |   sad1  |asd
```

everything's working except displaying it in table format(main thing)
any idea?

Comment: `column -t` formats the input in columns, if that's what you need.

Comment: its useful when trying to display in table format when it looks like this `abc f1 asd` and using printf to display column name,but i need to get the value (A=abc) abc under column_header A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo tt | sed "s/[ABC=,]//g" file_name | column -t
```

You can use 'echo' to print column headers A B C if needed.

Comment: echo tt | sed "s/[ABC=,]//g" tt | awk '{print $1 " " $3}' | column -t   As you see $1 for 1st column $ for 3rd column, You can do like for anything else you want.

Comment: one more doubt, what if i have a lot of fields,with long string names, i can write whole thing as ABC but it would make ugly any work around? like A*C kinda?

Comment: you could define it the command line as a variable & use it.In the command line: $ var="ABC"     then $ echo tt | sed "s/[$var=,]//g" tt | column -t will do that

Comment: yes, i could do that , but it would be very big ,alot if i must say atleast 200chars :(

Comment: Well, there's no other way to specify that. If you want to match a  specific regular expression, then you have to type it!